# Selecting unique records after order by clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am maintaining history of operations on vehicles in a table and now I want to get few fields of the latest operation on each of the vehicle.

This is what I tried

```
SELECT HVeh.RefVehicleModel , HVeh.RefVehStatus , HVeh.ChangedDate
FROM HVeh
WHERE ChangedDate >= @X AND ChangedDate <= @Y
order by HVeh.RefVehicleModel, HVeh.ChangedDate DESC
```

and it returns

The above query returns me something as given below

```
X   1   2019-09-04 08:21:39.223
X   1   2019-09-03 13:47:48.943
X   1   2019-09-03 11:27:43.813
X   1   2019-09-03 10:57:12.080
```

however, I want to select only the **top row** now as it is the most latest entry and is of particular interest.

NOTE : If I use SELECT TOP 1, it only fetches top row of the whole returned table, however I have multiple entries(for each vehicle) as I said, I need "top" entry for each of them

Comment: Add `FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY` at the end.

Comment: Most if not all databases have a `SELECT TOP 1` or `SELECT ... LIMIT 1`. Which one are you using?

Comment: What is your DBMS?

Comment: I am using SQL Server

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES HVeh.RefVehicleModel, HVeh.RefVehStatus, HVeh.ChangedDate
FROM HVeh
WHERE ChangedDate >= @X AND ChangedDate <= @Y
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY HVeh.RefVehicleModel ORDER BY HVeh.ChangedDate DESC);
```

Comment: it only fetches top row of the whole returned table, however i have multiple entries(for each vehicle) as i said and i need "top" entry for each of them

Comment: @SaadKhattak, you should have better sample data _and also_ the expected result showing that.

Comment: Thanks a bundle!! You are a genius :D

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Can i also get count of HVeh.RefVehStatus in the same query somehow?

Comment: That's a different query for a different question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the latest record for each vehicle model, then use a correlated subquery or window functions:

```
SELECT RefVehicleModel, RefVehStatus, ChangedDate
FROM (SELECT HVeh.RefVehicleModel, HVeh.RefVehStatus, HVeh.ChangedDate,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY HVeh.RefVehicleModel ORDER BY HVeh.ChangedDate DESC) as seqnum
      FROM HVeh
      WHERE ChangedDate >= @X AND ChangedDate <= @Y
     ) h
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

If you want only one record, then `SELECT TOP (1)` is a good solution.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT HVeh.RefVehicleModel , HVeh.RefVehStatus , HVeh.ChangedDate
FROM HVeh
WHERE 
convert(DATETIME,ChangedDate)   
BETWEEN Convert(DATETIME,CASE WHEN isnull(@X,'')='' THEN ChangedDate ELSE isnull(@X,'') END)                     
AND Convert(DATETIME, CASE WHEN isnull(@Y,'')='' THEN ChangedDate ELSE isnull(@Y,'') END)  
order by HVeh.RefVehicleModel, CONVERT(DATETIME,HVeh.ChangedDate,106)  DESC
```

I think this query will perfect for you....

Note:- @X as FromDate and @Y as ToDate