# Selecting records from already returned results from another query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am maintaining history of operations on vehicles in a table and after executing a query to fetch records based on transactions, I want to select records based on LIKE condition from this already returned results from the mentioned query

This is the query I am using (thanks to @TimBiegeleisen from
 [Selecting unique records after order by clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57820308/selecting-unique-records-after-order-by-clause) )

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES HVeh.RefVehicleModel, HVeh.RefVehStatus, HVeh.ChangedDate
FROM HVeh
WHERE ChangedDate >= @X AND ChangedDate <= @Y
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY HVeh.RefVehicleModel ORDER BY HVeh.ChangedDate DESC);
```

What I want is to expect results from this query and filter them lets say based on parked location of the vehicle.. Something like

```
Select A,B,C from tblSites and (SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES.. - this query)
where tblSites.Location LIKE '%LDN%'.....
```

P.S. I cannot use this LIKE conditions to the current query as it will affect the returned results which can result in returning of the result that was not the latest modified record (which I dont want)

I think I can try something Like as the following (adding this to the end of the current query) but I am not sure if its the best approach

```
 INNER JOIN Sites on Sites.Id = sd.Id AND Sites.Place LIKE '%LDN%'
```

`sd` refers to the alias of the first sub-query

Comment: how is `tblSites ` and the result of your first query related ?

Comment: based on foreignkey ref ```RefSites``` in the ```HVeh``` table

Comment: Please add sample data to your question.  As it stands now, it won't be very helpful to anyone in the future.

Answer (score 2):

You can always use a subquery or CTE.

Subquery:

```
SELECT ....
FROM tblSites INNER JOIN (
  SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES HVeh.Id, HVeh.RefVehicleModel, HVeh.RefVehStatus, HVeh.ChangedDate
  FROM HVeh
  WHERE ChangedDate >= @X AND ChangedDate <= @Y
  ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY HVeh.RefVehicleModel ORDER BY HVeh.ChangedDate DESC)) sd ON sd.Id = tblSites.id
WHERE tblSites.Location LIKE '%LDN%'
```

Note: since you have not specified what columns to select I have used the `....` placeholder. Replace it with the required column names.

Alternatively you can use CTE:

```
;WITH sd AS (
  SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES HVeh.Id, HVeh.RefVehicleModel, HVeh.RefVehStatus, HVeh.ChangedDate
  FROM HVeh
  WHERE ChangedDate >= @X AND ChangedDate <= @Y
  ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY HVeh.RefVehicleModel ORDER BY HVeh.ChangedDate DESC))
SELECT ....
FROM tblSites INNER JOIN sd ON sd.Id = tblSites.id
WHERE tblSites.Location LIKE '%LDN%'
```

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I was thinking of how to go about it...! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery.  But, if you are going to do so, don't use `TOP (1) WITH TIES`.  Although the method works, it is not the most efficient method -- basically because it has to calculate the `ROW_NUMBER()` and sort all the data.

So, I would recommend:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM tblSites s INNER JOIN
     (SELECT HVeh.Id, HVeh.RefVehicleModel, HVeh.RefVehStatus, HVeh.ChangedDate,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY HVeh.RefVehicleModel ORDER BY HVeh.ChangedDate DESC) as seqnum
      FROM HVeh
      WHERE ChangedDate >= @X AND ChangedDate <= @Y
     ) sd
     ON sd.id = s.id AND seqnum = 1
WHERE s.Location LIKE '%LDN%';
```

If you want the results in a particular order, you can add an `ORDER BY` to the outer query.